# Create layered objects from another layered object

Tags: javascript, object

I need to create a new object from another. For example.
This is an old object:

```js
const objectOld = { 
  level1: { 
    level2: { 
      level3: { 
        code: 123, 
        error: 'Message' 
      }  
    } 
  } 
}
```

and this my new object which created based on the old object.

```js
const objectNew = { 
  level1: { 
    level2: { 
      level3: { 
        error: {
           code: 123, 
           key: 'Message' 
        }
      }  
    } 
  } 
}
```

The depth may be different, of course.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with recusion, Array#reduce, Object#entries, some destruction.

This will deep copy your object and will create the `{ error: { code: string, key: string } }` if it detects an object with `code` and `message` properties.

If the object does not have those properties, it'll self call itself and continue.

If the `value` is not an object, keep the value as is.

```js
const objectOld = { 
  level1: { 
    level2: { 
      level3: { 
        code: 123, 
        error: 'Message' 
      }  
    } 
  } 
};


function transform(obj){
  return Object
  .entries(obj)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value])=>{
    if(typeof value === 'object'){
      if("code" in value && "error" in value){
        acc[key] = {
          error: {
            key: value.error,
            code: value.code
          }
        }
      } else {
        acc[key] = transform(value)
      }
    } else {
      acc[key] = value;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

const objectNew = transform(objectOld);

console.log(
  objectNew
);
```

Comment: Perfect! I suspected that recursion can help me. But I can't to do it.

Comment: @АннаВендерова you *can* . Takes some practice.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to copy that object? For deep copy you can use

```
const newObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(oldObj))
```

Comment: No, it's not only copy. I know how to copy. It's how to create a new object partially based on old. Just look into old and new object.

Answer (score 0):

Use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) javascript library for deep copy.

```
const objectOld = { 
  level1: { 
    level2: { 
      level3: { 
        code: 123, 
        error: 'Message' 
      }  
    } 
  } 
}

var objectNew = _.cloneDeep(objectOld);

console.log(objectNew === objectOld)
```

Comment: No, it's not only copy. I know how to copy. It's how to create a new object partially based on old. Just look into old and new object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generic utility that calls a transformation function for each key-value pair in the object and apply it recursively:

```js
function transform(obj, fn) {
    function transformer(obj) {
        if (!obj || typeof obj !== 'object')
            return obj;
        if (Array.isArray(obj))
            return obj.map((v, k) => fn(v, k, transformer));
        return Object.fromEntries(
            Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => [k, fn(v, k, transformer)]));
    }
    return transformer(obj)
}

//

const objectOld = {
    level1: {
        level2: {
            level3: {
                code: 123,
                error: 'Message'
            }
        }
    },
    otherKey: { anotherOne: { code: 25, error: 'Message2'}}
}


let newObj = transform(objectOld, (val, key, trans) =>
    ('error' in val) ? {error: val} : trans(val)
)

console.log(newObj)
```

Comment: Good solution, thanks! Unfortunately I can't set your answer as a solution too. Only one answer :/